# Finding the expectation of a geometric distribution

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $X$ is geometric ($p$). This means that its distribution is given by $p_k = P(X = k) = (1-p)^kp$ where $p$ is probability of success: $0 \leq p \leq 1 $. I am trying to find $\mathbb{E} \left\{ \frac{1}{1+X} \right\} $:

What I got:

$$ \mathbb{E} \left\{ \frac{1}{1 + X} \right\}  = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+k} (1-p)^kp = \frac{p}{1-p} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{ (1-p)^{k+1}}{k+1} = \frac{p}{1-p} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(1-p)^k}{k} = \frac{p}{1-p} \log ( (1-p) + 1 ) = \boxed{ \log(2 - p)^{ \frac{p}{1-p}}}$$

However, my book states that the answer should be

$$ \log(1 - p)^{ \frac{p}{1-p}}$$

So, either I am wrong or the book has a typo. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should handle the case $p=1$ separately. In that case, $\frac{1}{1+X}=1$ always.

For $0 \le p < 1$, I think you got the Taylor series wrong. However, I am getting something different from your book's answer...
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{1+X}\right]
&= \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{1}{1+k} (1-p)^k p\\
&= \frac{p}{1-p} \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{(1-p)^{k+1}}{k+1}\\
&= \frac{p}{1-p} \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{(1-p)^{k}}{k}\\
&= - \frac{p}{1-p}\log(1-(1-p))\\
&= - \frac{p}{1-p}\log p\\
\end{align*}

Comment: This answer looks correct. The book's answer is wrong because it gives a negative number for every p and we are taking the average of positive numbers.